# Upgrade Wheezy -> Jessie Unable to install procps

Tags: debian, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my Debian Wheezy to Jessie, but it failed during the `apt-get dist-upgrade`, and now I am completely stocked.

Here is what happens when I try a `apt-get dist-upgrade` :

```
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libgnutls-dev libgvc5 libkadm5srv-mit8 librtmp-dev ruby-actionmailer-2.3 ruby-actionpack-2.3 ruby-activerecord-2.3 ruby-activeresource-2.3 ruby-rails-2.3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cpp-4.8 emacsen-common firmware-linux-free fonts-dejavu-extra gcc-4.8 gcc-4.8-base guile-2.0-libs icu-devtools imagemagick-6.q16 init iproute2 irqbalance
  libasan0 libasound2-data libasprintf-dev libatm1 libb-hooks-op-check-perl libbareword-filehandles-perl libbind9-90 libboost-iostreams1.55.0 libcap-ng0
  libcdt5 libcgraph6 libclass-method-modifiers-perl libcupsfilters1 libdebconfclient0 libdevel-globaldestruction-perl libdns-export100 libdns100
  libdrm-nouveau2 libefivar0 libestr0 libexiv2-13 libfakeroot libfftw3-double3 libfl-dev libgcc-4.8-dev libgcrypt20-dev libgettextpo-dev libgmp-dev
  libgmpxx4ldbl libgnutls-deb0-28 libgnutlsxx28 libgraphite2-3 libgvc6 libgvpr2 libharfbuzz0b libhogweed2 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl
  libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libimport-into-perl
  libindirect-perl libintl-perl libio-html-perl libirs-export91 libisc-export95 libisc95 libisccc90 libisccfg-export90 libisccfg90 libjs-excanvas
  libkadm5clnt-mit9 libkadm5srv-mit9 libkdb5-7 libkyotocabinet16 liblexical-sealrequirehints-perl libllvm3.5 liblogging-stdlog0 liblognorm1
  liblwp-protocol-https-perl liblwres90 libmagickcore-6.q16-2 libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-2 libmoo-perl libmspack0
  libmultidimensional-perl libnet-http-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnettle4 libnuma1 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangox-1.0-0
  libpangoxft-1.0-0 libpsl0 libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib librole-tiny-perl librtmp1 libsasl2-modules-db libsctp1
  libstrictures-perl libsub-exporter-progressive-perl libtasn1-6 libtcl8.5 libtext-unidecode-perl libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libwebp5 libwebpdemux1 libwebpmux1
  libwww-perl libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-sync1 libxml-libxml-perl libxml-namespacesupport-perl libxml-parser-perl
  libxml-sax-base-perl libxml-sax-expat-perl libxml-sax-perl libxshmfence1 libxtables10 linux-compiler-gcc-4.8-x86 linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64
  linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64 linux-kbuild-3.16 lksctp-tools nettle-dev openjdk-7-jre-headless openssh-sftp-server
  python-defusedxml python-pil python-pyinotify python-six python-wstools qtcore4-l10n ruby ruby-activesupport ruby-atomic ruby-minitest
  ruby-net-http-persistent ruby-thor ruby-thread-safe ruby2.1 ruby2.1-dev systemd-sysv zsh-common
The following packages have been kept back:
  db5.1-util
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ack-grep acpid apt apt-utils aptitude aptitude-common at avahi-daemon base-passwd bind9 bind9-host bind9utils bsdutils build-essential bundler cabextract
  clamav-base cron curl dbus default-jre-headless dictionaries-common dmsetup dnsutils docutils-common dovecot-core dovecot-imapd dovecot-mysql
  dovecot-pop3d dovecot-sieve dselect efibootmgr fail2ban fakeroot fcgiwrap flex gettext ghostscript gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-glib-2.0
  gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 imagemagick imagemagick-common iproute iptables iputils-ping isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common krb5-multidev libapt-pkg4.12 libasound2
  libasprintf0c2 libatk-wrapper-java-jni libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libcairo-gobject2 libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2 libclamav7
  libclass-accessor-grouped-perl libcryptsetup4 libcups2 libcupsimage2 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4-gnutls-dev libcwidget3 libdevmapper1.02.1
  libdjvulibre-dev libdjvulibre21 libept1.4.12 libffi-dev libgcrypt11-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgettextpo0 libgirepository-1.0-1
  libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libgnutls-openssl27 libgraphviz-dev libgs9 libgs9-common libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssrpc4 libgtk2.0-0
  libgtk2.0-bin libicu-dev libio-socket-ssl-perl libjasper-dev libjasper1 libjson0 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libkrb5-dev libkrb5support0 libldap-2.4-2
  libldap2-dev libmailtools-perl libmailutils4 libmng1 libnetpbm10 libopenexr-dev libopenexr6 libp11-kit-dev libp11-kit0 libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin
  libpam0g libpango1.0-0 libpaper1 libpathplan4 libpulse0 libpython2.7 libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-xml libqtcore4 libqtdbus4 libqtgui4 librsvg2-2
  librsvg2-common libruby libsasl2-2 libsemanage-common libsemanage1 libsnmp-base libsql-abstract-perl libssh2-1 libssh2-1-dev libsystemd-journal0
  libusb-1.0-0 libvncserver0 libwmf-dev libwmf0.2-7 libxapian22 libxdot4 libxft2 libxslt1-dev libxslt1.1 linux-headers-amd64 linux-image-amd64 login lynx
  lynx-cur mailutils mailutils-common memcached mercurial mercurial-common netpbm openbsd-inetd openssh-client openssh-server passwd postfix postfix-mysql
  procps pslib1 python python-apt python-chardet python-debian python-docutils python-imaging python-minimal python-pkg-resources python-pygments
  python-reportbug python-soappy python2.7 python2.7-minimal reportbug rsyslog ruby-activesupport-2.3 ruby-dev ruby-ffi ruby-json ruby-mysql ruby-tzinfo
  shared-mime-info sudo sysvinit tcl8.5 texinfo ttf-dejavu-extra ufraw-batch webalizer wget zsh zsh-doc
193 upgraded, 148 newly installed, 9 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 914 kB/213 MB of archives.
After this operation, 309 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Get:1 http://ftp.cn.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main librtmp1 amd64 2.4+20150115.gita107cef-1 [59.8 kB]
Get:2 http://ftp.cn.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libgnutlsxx28 amd64 3.3.8-6+deb8u3 [14.6 kB]
Get:3 http://ftp.cn.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main nettle-dev amd64 2.7.1-5+deb8u1 [839 kB]
Fetched 914 kB in 1s (566 kB/s)
Reading changelogs... Done
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'postgresql-client-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'postgresql-client-9.1' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 80932 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../procps_2%3a3.3.9-9_amd64.deb ...
Failed to parse message: No such device or address
```

Apt will stock at `Failes to parse message...` and I have to kill the process :

```
✘ erwan@gm  ~  ps aux | grep apt
root     16356  0.0  0.0  55096  2008 pts/3    S+   10:33   0:00 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
root     16357  0.1  0.6  85804 49696 pts/3    S+   10:33   0:00 apt-get dist-upgrade
root     18562  0.0  0.2  42436 20264 pts/18   Ss+  10:33   0:00 /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 36 --unpack --auto-deconfigure /var/cache/apt/archives/procps_2%3a3.3.9-9_amd64.deb
erwan    18804  0.0  0.0  12720  1012 pts/15   S+   10:42   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn apt
 erwan@gm  ~  sudo kill 18562
```

Than I execute a `apt-get update` and it ends with this message :
    Eg: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to correct the problem.

And here is the result of `sudo dpkg --configure -a` :

```
 ✘ erwan@gm  /etc/apt  sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error processing package procps (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udev:
 udev depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd:
 systemd depends on udev (>= 208-8); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd-shim:
 systemd-shim depends on cgmanager (>= 0.32); however:
  Package cgmanager is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package systemd-shim (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-systemd:amd64:
 libpam-systemd:amd64 depends on systemd (= 215-17+deb8u4); however:
  Package systemd is not configured yet.
 libpam-systemd:amd64 depends on systemd-shim (>= 8-2) | systemd-sysv; however:
  Package systemd-shim is not configured yet.
  Package systemd-sysv is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 procps
 udev
 systemd
 systemd-shim
 libpam-systemd:amd64
```

I also tried : `sudo apt-get download procps`

and then :

```
 erwan@gm  ~  sudo dpkg --force-all -i procps_3.3.9-9_amd64.deb
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'postgresql-client-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'postgresql-client-9.1' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 80932 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack procps_3.3.9-9_amd64.deb ...
Failed to parse message: No such device or address
^Cdpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script was interrupted
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Failed to parse message: No such device or address
^Cdpkg: error processing archive procps_3.3.9-9_amd64.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-removal script was interrupted
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Failed to parse message: No such device or address
^Cdpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script was interrupted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 procps_3.3.9-9_amd64.deb
```

but as you can see it also failed.

I have no idea what to do now...
Please help me!!

### EDIT :

@Stephen

I tried your suggestion but it still the same :

```
erwan@gm  ~  sudo rm /etc/init.d/procps
erwan@gm  ~  sudo dpkg --force-all -i procps_3.3.9-9_amd64.deb
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'postgresql-client-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'postgresql-client-9.1' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 80932 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack procps_3.3.9-9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking procps (2:3.3.9-9) over (2:3.3.9-9) ...
Setting up procps (2:3.3.9-9) ...

Configuration file `/etc/init.d/procps', does not exist on system.
Installing new config file as you requested.

Configuration file '/etc/sysctl.conf'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
     Version in package is the same as at last installation.
 ==> Keeping old config file as default.
Failed to parse message: No such device or address

^Cdpkg: error processing package procps (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script was interrupted
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 procps
```

Then I still tried to update and dist-upgrade but it still failed for the same reasons :

```
Fetched 63.3 MB in 1min 28s (712 kB/s)
Reading changelogs... Done
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up procps (2:3.3.9-9) ...
Failed to parse message: No such device or address
```

Comment: The failure is rather odd, but the script involved is innocuous — could you try deleting `/etc/init.d/procps`, then reinstalling `procps` from the file you downloaded?

Comment: @StephenKitt sorry I haven't been notified of your comment. I just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

The `Failed to parse message` is probably emitted by the DBus code in `systemd`. Try starting or configuring `dbus`. If that isn't possible, try disabling systemd's LSB hook like

```
_SYSTEMCTL_SKIP_REDIRECT=true dpkg --configure procps
```